# IBM MobileFirst 6.3 JSONStore remove issue in JS

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I'm using

```
WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).remove(doc)
```

in my code and sometimes it doesn't remove docs, not even mark them deleted. What can I possibly do wrong?
By the way, this:

```
WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).clear()
```

works fine.

**UPDATE:**

Ok, here some code, and it's result in my browser.

```
var collectionName = 'samplecollection';
var data = [{"name":"Jimbo"},{"name":"Patrick"},{"name":"Alex"},{"name":"Sam"},{"name":"Charlie"},{"name":"Donnie"}];

WL.JSONStore.init({samplecollection:{}}).then(function() {
    WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).add(data).then(function(){
        WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).findAll().then(function(docs){
            var promises = [];
            docs.forEach(function(doc){
                console.log(doc);
                var promise = WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).remove(doc);
                promises.push(promise);
            });
            $.when.apply(null, promises).done(function() {
                WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).findAll().then(function(docs){
                    console.table(docs);
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

[image: code result in chrome]

I expected console.table to display an empty array. But it's not empty. It doesn't have all saved objects either. So I'm trying to understand what is going on here. Any ideas?

Comment: .clear() Deletes the entire content of your collection. Can you elaborate on what the situation is? Please provide more details on what is happening, such as log output and your code that is failing. For example, it could be that you are not using the APIs asynchronously and are running into race conditions, but I can't tell these things without the relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSONStore for JS does not work well with parallel requests from my experience. You could use something like async.js to create serial request.

I cover some of this in this blog https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/02/24/working-jsonstore-collections-join/